# Chaining assignment statements in Java

Tags: java, operators, variable-assignment, swap

Here is a lame implementation of the [XOR swap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm):

```
char a = 'a', b = 'b';
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
System.out.println(a + " " + b);
```

The output is `b a`, as expected. As far as I know, the assignment operator in Java returns the assigned value, which means the following code *should* yield the same result:

```
a ^= (b ^= (a ^= b));
```

However, this one only prints `a`. Also, to my surprise, another two variants both output `b a`:

- variant 1 (works fine):

  ```
  a ^= b;
  a ^= (b ^= a);
  ```
- variant 2 (also works fine):

  ```
  b ^= (a ^= b);
  a ^= b;
  ```

I'm really confused. Why can I chain two assignments, but not three?

**Edit:**

For your reference, the following C code outputs `b a`, which is how I came up with this question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a = 'a', b = 'b';
    a ^= (b ^= (a ^= b));
    printf("%c %c\n", a, b);
}
```

Comment: I'mma say this just to be sure it's said:  C isn't Java and Java doesn't share the same operator priorities.  There are *similarities* but that doesn't mean C code will be exactly equivalent to Java code if you just copy the same syntax.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for pointing that out, but I've put parentheses around the operators. I suppose that will make sure operators are evaluated in the same order in these two languages?

Comment: Normally, that would happen.  I'm seeing some strange results in my IDE which would beg to differ.  I'll try to distill this into an answer.

Comment: ...alternatively I could find an answer which appears to cover the same ground...

Comment: @Makoto Oh thanks! TIL...